# Sublime (JavaScript) reindentation adds a space on the beginning of the code

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I started using Sublime Text 2 to edit .js files and installed Sublime Linter.
Also, I imported eclipse shortcuts because that's what I'm used to. (saw here:  https://gist.github.com/thbkrkr/3194275)

My problem is that when I reindent my .js file, if that file has a comment on the beginning, my first line of code gets a single space added before it, and all lines of code get aligned by that first line, algo getting that single space added...

Because of that I get the warning "Mixed space and tabs" in almost every single line of my file.

What should I do to prevent that space from being added when I reindent my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Sublime Text 2? 3? Or just 1?

Comment: Sublime Text 2 (edited)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 8, 64. I answered this already, btw. It works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it.

I wrote the comment on eclipse in Java style.

Because of that, the comment was something like:

```java
/*
 *
 *
 */
```

So, when reindenting, it continued with that space alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2 has settings which keep indentation consistent with the previous line, so if your comment has 1-space indentations:

```
/*
 * Notice how all these lines, including the last one,
 * have an extra 1-space indentation at their start,
 * (it's what keeps the asterisks aligned)
 */
```

That 1-space indentation will continue until you hit backspace to get rid of it.

You can change these settings manually,

Edit **%appdata%\Sublime Text 2\Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings**, line 59, from

```
"auto_indent": true,
```

to

```
"auto_indent": false,
```

You could alternatively change your User settings,

%appdata%\Sublime Text 2\Packages/**User**/Preferences.sublime-settings

to contain this new line.

Comment: @LuisSilva did you restart sublime? And remember to save the new file?